# Total hours between dates using T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I'm looking for an T-Sql script to calculate total hours between 2 dates, but only if it falls into a certain period.

I have a table called Complaints with various columns including ContactDate and ResolvedDate.

I only want to calculate the total time in hours if it falls within our opening hours. 9-5pm Mon-Fri and 12-4pm Sat and Sun.

So for example, if I got a complaint on the 5th Dec at 3pm and Resolved it on the 6th Dec at 1pm, the total hours would be 3.

Another example would be I got a complaint on the 3rd Dec and 12pm and Resolved it on the 6th Dec at 5pm, the total hours would be 24 hours.

I would like that value to pull into each row for my report.

Comment: What have you researched, tried on your own, and found to not work? So far this post shows no effort on your part at all.

Comment: Can you post what you have actually tried so far? If you have any at that, just so we can try and help you do it? :)

Comment: Where's your attempt?  We can help you fix your query, but we don't create query for you.  Do you even do some research?  There are a lot of example online.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I'm not doing all of this for you but this will give you an option. I'd create a table with a row of data for each hour. In this I would have a flag to show whether it is a working hour or not, something like this;

```
CREATE TABLE #DateTable (Time_Stamp datetime, Working_Hour int)
INSERT INTO #DateTable (Time_Stamp, Working_Hour)
VALUES
 ('2016-12-05 14:00:00',1)
,('2016-12-05 15:00:00',1)
,('2016-12-05 16:00:00',1)
,('2016-12-05 17:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-05 18:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-05 19:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-05 20:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-05 21:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-05 22:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-05 23:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-05 00:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-06 01:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-06 02:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-06 03:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-06 04:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-06 05:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-06 06:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-06 07:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-06 08:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-06 09:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-06 10:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-06 11:00:00',0)
,('2016-12-06 12:00:00',1)
,('2016-12-06 13:00:00',1)
,('2016-12-06 14:00:00',1)
,('2016-12-06 15:00:00',1)
```

Sample Call List;

```
CREATE TABLE #Calls (Call_ID int, StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime)
INSERT INTO #Calls (Call_ID, StartDate, EndDate)
VALUES
 (1,'2016-12-05 14:00:00','2016-12-06 14:00:00')
,(2,'2016-12-05 15:00:00','2016-12-06 14:00:00')
,(3,'2016-12-05 16:00:00','2016-12-06 14:00:00')
```

That way you can join to this using your two dates and sum how many working hours between them, like this;

```
SELECT
     c.Call_ID
    ,SUM(dt.Working_Hour) Working_Hour
FROM #Calls c
JOIN #DateTable dt
    ON dt.Time_Stamp BETWEEN c.StartDate AND c.EndDate
GROUP BY c.Call_ID
```

Result;

```
Call_ID Working_Hour
1       6
2       5
3       4
```

If you google 'date table sql' there are plenty of examples to help you populate the date table.

Comment: I've been looking online most of the day without any luck.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Rich however I don't want a single result populated with hard coded dates. I need the result to populate each row of my report

Comment: Why is there so much hostility? Isn't this a source for help or information

Comment: @FastEddie I've updated my answer to show you how to do it from a table list and a join. There's often a little hostility to new users on SO unfortunately. The reason is the number of people who ask a question and either don't supply enough information or don't look like they've attempted anything themselves. I find people here are happy to help others but they resent being seen as a free coding service. One of those things I guess.

Answer (score 0):

From memory when I did this before... (it's not pretty)

```
with CTE as
(
select CaseID, cast(ComplaintDate as date) as ComplaintDate, cast(CompaintDate as time) as CompTime, cast(ResolvedDate as date) as ResolvedDate, cast(ResolvedDate as time) as ResolvedTime,
case
  when datepart(dw,ResolvedDate) in (1,7) then cast('12:00:00' as TIME)
  else cast('09:00:00' as time)
end as ResStart,
case
  when datepart(dw,CompaintDate) in (1,7) then cast('16:00:00') as time
  else cast('17:00:00' as time)
end as ComEnd
from Compaints
)
select CaseID,
case
when datepart(dd, ResolvedDate) > datepart(dd,ComplaintDate) then
  datediff(hh, ResolvedTime, ResStart) + datediff(hh,ComEnd,ComplaintTime) + 8*datediff(dd,ResolvedDate,ComplaintDate)
else DateDiff(hh,ResolvedTime,ComplaintTime)
end as HoursOpen
from CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

We actually perform the calculations in minutes so you decide to round up/down, but the result is returned in hours.

I should note that the code in the CROSS APPLY could easily be migrated into a UDF.

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,OpenDT datetime, CloseDT datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'2016-12-02 16:00','2016-12-05 10:00'),
(2,'2016-12-02 16:00','2016-12-05 09:45'),
(3,'2016-12-07 09:00','2016-12-08 11:15')

Select A.*
      ,B.BusinessHours
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select BusinessHours=count(*)/60.0 
                 From (Select Top (DateDiff(MI,A.OpenDT,A.CloseDT)+5000) D=DateAdd(MI,Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL))-1,cast(cast(A.OpenDT as date) as datetime)) From master..spt_values N1,master..spt_values N2) D
                 Where  D > A.OpenDT and D<= A.CloseDT
                   and (
                        (DatePart(DW,D) between 2 and 6 and cast(D as time) between '09:01' and '17:00') 
                        or  
                        (DatePart(DW,D) = 7 and cast(D as time) between '12:01' and '16:00')
                        )
       ) B
```

Returns

[image]

As an added bonus, you can exclude holidays as well  **(should be an actual table)**

```
and  Cast(D as Date) Not In (Select Date From (Values 
                                       ('2016-01-01','New Year''s Day'),
                                       ('2016-01-18','Martin Luther King, Jr,'),
                                       ('2016-02-15','Washington''s Birthday'),
                                       ('2016-03-25','Good Friday'),
                                       ('2016-05-30','Memorial Day'),
                                       ('2016-07-04','Independence Day'),
                                       ('2016-09-05','Labor Day'),
                                       ('2016-11-24','Thanksgiving'),
                                       ('2016-11-25','Black Friday'),
                                       ('2016-12-26','Christmas Day') 
                                ) as H (Date,Name))
```